# How do i execute redbird in a Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, proxy, reverse, redbird

So, this is the first problem that I didn't find any answer around the internet.

So, basically I have a redbird app that works as expected and i decided to put it inside a Docker container (don't wanna run screen or tmux, etc).

So i created a Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /var/WebService/apps/redbird

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["node", "app"]
```

and a docker-compose.yml as follow:

```
version: "3"

services:
    redbird:
        container_name: redbird
        build: .
        command: npm start
        ports:
            - "80"
            - "443"
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: PRODUCTION
```

and it doesn't work.

My thoughts are:

- Docker does not have access to port 80 and 443. (yes, i'm running as root and i know it is not recommended).
- Docker is not mapping the ports inside the container to my external LAN.

And, why people are not talking about redbird? i found 0 help about redbird.

Comment: In what way doesn’t it work?  That form of `ports:` asks Docker to pick the host port; it avoids some potential conflicts but is harder to use.

Comment: The request doesn't work. I access domain.com and it can't connect to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need docker-compose to execute a docker container. You also have images of redbird at dockerhub such as https://hub.docker.com/r/myuserindocker/redbird-reverseproxy.

```
docker run --rm -p 80:80 -p 443:443 myuserindocker/redbird-reverseproxy
```

Comment: Hey, i need to use this image that I'm creating, it's not the default redbird. Ane the problem is actually binding ports using docker because it works fine if i just run like npm start

Comment: It seems a format problem to me. I would recommend to build it in docker and after checking it take a look at the docker-compose file. This code should work:

"docker build -t user/myimage:latest ." and 
"docker run --rm -p 80:80 -p 443:443 user/myimage:latest".

Please if it's prompting an error, add it

Comment: Also I don't know if docker binds the ports just saying "80" and not "80:80". If you're sure it's port binding try to use the complete argument. The other options in your file are fine.